# Meteor application not pushing to Heroku error

Tags: heroku, meteor, sass, bourbon

I built a Meteor app that uses the bourbon scss library. I tried to push my app to heroku got the following error:

```
    Errors prevented bundling:
    While building the application:
    client/styles/bullets.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/bullets.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/comments.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/main.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/hero.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/hero.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/home.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/home.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/hover.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/main.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/navigation.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/main.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/registration.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/registration.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
    client/styles/main.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/main.scss:1:
    file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon/bourbon"
    Current dir:
    /tmp/build_52129b38b75a2e6238de86ec866d89cf/mauvsa-gala-9a1eb00877caedf4b5202f30825b1627fb75f874/client/styles/
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Apparently, it's not able to find the scss files, although they are in my client/styles folder. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and finally removed the meteor-bourbon, meteor-neat, and meteor-bitters packages and added them via bower instead.

Add this bower meteor package: `mquandalle:bower`

`Bower init` to get your bower.json (I just put it in the root of the directory) and add your bourbon/neat/bitters dependencies. DON'T bower install them as meteor automatically does it. If you did, just delete the bower_components folder.

The bottom of my `bower.json`:

`"dependencies": {
    "bourbon": "4.2.1",
    "neat": "1.7.2",
    "bitters": "1.0.0"
  }`

Then import the files from their location in /.meteor/local/. For example, in my `main.scss` I have:

`@import "./.meteor/local/bower/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
@import "./.meteor/local/bower/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/neat";
@import "./.meteor/local/bower/bitters/app/assets/stylesheets/base";`

Then I was able to push to heroku successfully...I hope it works for you too!